# Limits of Absolute Values

Tags: calculus, limits

I can prove that if $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to c} f(x) = L$, then $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to c} |f(x)| = |L|$.

However, while I know that - conversely - if $\lim_{x \to c} |(f(x)| = |L|$ , $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)$ does not *necessarily* equal $L$, I don't know how to prove it. How can I?

Comment: Hint: $|f(x)|=|(-1)^{D(x)}f(x)|$ where $D(x)$ is the _Dirichlet function_.

Comment: Even simpler: consider the constant function $f=-1$, and $L=+1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $f(x) = 1, x > 0$, and $f(x) = -1 , x < 0$. Can this help? ( didn't look at comment above while cooking this example ! )

Comment: Isn't this a discontinuous piecewise function, meaning a limit would not exist at all?

Comment: The function needs NOT be continuous at $x = c$ with $c = 0$ in this example.

Comment: So how would I go about proving that if $\lim_{x \to c} |(f(x)| = |L|$ , $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)$ does not *necessarily* equal $L$?

Comment: My answer above is the counter example for the question you asked .

Comment: Right, but if c=0 according to your counter example, then the limit of f(x)=1 as x -> 0 would be 1, and the limit of f(x)=-1 as x-> 0 would be -1. Thus a constant limit could not exist for f(x), correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right. But for $|f(x)|$ it has the limit of $1$.

Comment: I see, so are you saying that both f(x) for x>0 and f(x) for x<0 must be simultaneously considered when plugging in values into the counter example?

Comment: Yes. I think so.